# Are there any dress codes for righteous gentiles during prayers?

Tags: tefilla, gentiles, clothing

In Judaism, while not obligated to, the Jews wear Tallit and Teffilin during some prayers.

What about the Gentiles - are there special clothes or items for righteous Gentiles to wear during prayers?

Comment: Sorry that I can't provide a source but from what I heard you should dress respectably like Jews do - the way you'd dress to meet a president or king

Comment: You got it wrong. We don't wear Tefillin or Tzitzis for the prayer, we combine some Mitzvos. Those are not necessary at all. Also what about Jewish women? They don't wear any special items.

Comment: I'm confused now after your edit - are you asking about clothes or special religious items?

Comment: @AlBerko yes, that's what I am asking for

Comment: I asked "OR" and you answer "Yes" ?!

Comment: @AlBerko I misunderstood your question because I am asking about both clothes and religious items

Comment: See also that a non-Jew is allowed to wear Teffilin here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17789/can-a-non-jew-don-tefillin

Comment: THey are also allowed to wear Tallit / Tzitzit https://www.quora.com/Can-a-non-Jew-wrap-tefillin-and-tallit-when-he-prays-1

Answer (score 3):

Let me just outline some basic ideas:

1. Judaism does not deal with the details of Gentile observance beyond the 7 Noahide laws.
2. Prayer is not one of those laws. Gentiles are free to express themselves in prayers and praises (*or bring the sacrifices to the Jewish Temple once it returns B"H*) in any way they like because those are optional.
3. Gentiles (and Jews also) are not divided into righteous and sinful, the same laws apply to all.
4. Anything that does not override the 7 laws (*idolatrous or adulterous pictures, for instance*) would be fine.

Comment: +1, but to respond to your point #3: while it's true that the laws are the same, the term "righteous gentiles" is a colloquial term that is used to refer to gentiles who follow the 7 Noahide laws. They're specified in the questions because, presumably, they're the gentiles who care about the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no obligation for a Noahide to wear garments for prayers (if they do pray). The main point is that Noahides should not create for themself (in their own mind) a religious precept to wear a specific garment (something like a Jewish tallis or something similar to it), because he would be creating for himself an innovated commandment, which is forbidden.

Comment: -1 - where exactly "*creating for himself an innovated commandment, which is forbidden*"? Never heard of such limitation for Gentiles. the Tallis has little connection with Teffilah it is not "a garment for Tefilah".

Comment: Creating a new commandment for noahides is forbidden regardless if it is connected to tefillah or no.

Comment: @Al https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80394/

Comment: You totally misunderstand the idea of adding Mitzvos. If they say that G-d commanded 8 or 10 laws that would be forbidden put to accept additional decrees - just as our Rabbinical Mitzvas it is welcomed - that's what their courts are for..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you are. The (social) laws by the noahide court is not considered adding a religious precept or creating a new religion. SMH helek 1 perek 3:10 notedly brings that distinction.